# Writing Client and Server, UDP

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I'm trying to write a simple client and server using UDP.

I can send data from the client to the server, and the server recieves it well, but when I send the data from the server to the client, it doesnt work at all...
(It doesnt detect anything, and is stuck on `recvfrom` function..

Here is my Server code :

```
SOCKET ServerOn()
 {
SOCKET ListenSocket;
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
{
    exit(0);
}

// Create a SOCKET for listening for
// incoming connection requests.
ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{
    WSACleanup();
    exit(1);
}

// The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
// IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.
sockaddr_in service;
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
service.sin_port = htons(2583);

if (bind(ListenSocket,(SOCKADDR *) & service, sizeof (service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(2);
}

return ListenSocket;
}
```

In this function, I'm initializing the server on port 2583.

Here is my other code in the server :

```
int size = sizeof(service);
char *data = new char[500];

recvfrom(s,data, 500, NULL, (SOCKADDR*)&service, &size); // Getting a new connection

    sockaddr_in service;
 service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1");
service.sin_port = htons(2583);

    int addrSize = sizeof(service);
if (sendto(s, "123", 3, NULL, (struct sockaddr*)&service, addrSize) != 3)
    printf("%d", WSAGetLastError()); // Print error if did not send successfully
```

"10.0.0.1" is the IP of the Client (I made sure it is)...
I didnt found a way to get the IP automaticly from the socket, so I'm just putting it right away for now...

Here is my client code :

```
SOCKET ConnectToServer()
{
//----------------------
// Initialize Winsock
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) 
{
    return NULL;
}
//----------------------
// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
SOCKET ConnectSocket;
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    WSACleanup();
    return NULL;
}
//----------------------
// The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
// IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Default_IP.c_str()); // IP
clientService.sin_port = htons(Default_Port); // Port

//----------------------
// Connect to server.
iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof (clientService)); // Connecting
while (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) // ERROR, could not connect. keep trying
{
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof (clientService)); // Connecting
}

   return ConnectSocket;
    }
```

In this code, I'm connecting to the client.

and here is the rest of the client code :

```
    sockaddr_in service;
 service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1");
service.sin_port = htons(2583);
s = ConnectToServer();
sendto(s, "123", 3, NULL, (struct sockaddr*)&service, addrSize);

while(true)
{
    result = recvfrom(s, (char*)waveIn, NUMPTS * sizeof(short int), NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&service, &addrSize);

    if (result > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "New Data!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        printf("%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

the `sendto` function in the client does work, and the server recieves it, though when the server tries to send data back to the client, it recieves nothing, and it is stuck on the `recvfrom` function.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S - I'm running both client and server from the same computer, which means both has the same IP adress ("10.0.0.1"), but it allways worked for me when using sockets with TCP, so I've did it here too.

though, I did try use this code with 2 different computers, and I still had the same error...

Thanks!

Comment: UDP is connectionless - you should not try to connect to the server port.

Comment: @MartinJames What do you mean? in the client, change the port? how will it change my error, of the client not recieving anything ?

Comment: @MartinJames: UDP may be connectionless, but it is valid to call `connect()` on a UDP socket. It merely establishes a local static association between the local and remote IP:Port pairs, thus allowing use of `send()` and `recv()` vs `sento()` and `recvfrom()`, as well as error reporting if the receiver sends ICMP error packets to the sender (which would be ignored without `connect()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the server calls `recvfrom()`, it reports the IP:Port that the data came from.  You need to send your reply back to that same IP:Port, eg:

```
sockaddr_in service;
int size = sizeof(service);
char data[500];

int len = recvfrom(s, data, 500, NULL, (SOCKADDR*)&service, &size);
if (len == -1)
    printf("recv failed: %d", WSAGetLastError()); // Print error if did not recv successfully
else
{
    if (sendto(s, "123", 3, NULL, (struct sockaddr*)&service, size) == -1)
        printf("send failed: %d", WSAGetLastError()); // Print error if did not send successfully
}
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!!

The problem was, I was creating a new `sockaddr_in` in the `recvfrom`, and a new in the `sendfrom`, which caused the errors!

One question:
If I want to use multi-threading, as like, every new connection gets a new thread, do I need to pass the `sockaddr` to the thread, and intialize a new `sockaddr` to recieve a new connection, and use the same socket in all the threads? or I need a new socket for each connection? I hope I'm clear enough!

Thanks again!

Comment: There are no connections in UDP. You can reuse the original socket, or create a new socket, UDP does not care (TCP cares). As for the `sockaddr`, you can allocate it on the stack (like I showed) and pass a copy of it to each thread, or you can dynamically allocate a new `sockaddr` each time and have a thread take ownership of it. It does not really matter. What matters is the *content* of the `sockaddr`, not how the memory is managed.  As long as you pass an *equivalent* `sockaddr` to `sendto()` that represents the same IP:Port that `recvfrom()` reported, you will be fine.